# Contact.php cropping away Name

Tags: php, email, contact-form

I got a email.php from a website. How do you add an extra field to it, like phone number?
The original one I downloaded works fine.
Email comes as>>

> From: Nuski
>
> E-mail: my@email.com
>
> Subject: Test
>
> Message: Test mail

But when I add `$field_phone = $_POST['cf_phone'];` and `$body_message = "Phone: ".$field_phone."\n";`
The email comes without the Name of the sender. Like>>

> Phone: 5559
>
> E-mail: flex@f.com
>
> Subject: reCaptcha test
>
> Message: Email Test

Here is my HTML form

```
<form  action="email.php" method="post">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="cf_name" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="cf_phone" type="text" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="cf_email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="cf_subject" type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control btn-block" name="cf_message" id="comments" placeholder="Please include your address and item code for delivery" required></textarea><br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block" id="submit" value="Send Message">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <p class="contact-success">Your Message has been Successfully Sent!</p>
        <p class="contact-error">Error! Something went wrong!</p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is my email.php

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_phone = $_POST['cf_phone']; //added by me
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_subject = $_POST['cf_subject'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'ask@aki.co';
$subject = 'Message from AkiYTeeS - '.$field_subject;

$body_message = "From: ".$field_name."\n";
$body_message = "Phone: ".$field_phone."\n"; //added by me
$body_message .= "E-mail: ".$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= "Subject: ".$field_subject."\n";
$body_message .= "Message: ".$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to ');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Because you're **replacing** the `$body_message` instead of **appending** to it...

Comment: If any of the answers helped you than please check it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
$body_message = "Phone: ".$field_phone."\n"; //added by me
```

With:

```
$body_message .= "Phone: ".$field_phone."\n"; //added by me // You forgot a "." here
```

Also note that it's better to use `\r\n` unstead of just `\r` or `\n` as windows mac and linux each need a different of the 2 so by adding both it should always work

Answer (score 1):

```
$body_message = "Phone: ".$field_phone."\n";
```

You have forgotten the concatenation operator in the above line.
use "." (dot)

```
$body_message .= "Phone: ".$field_phone."\n";
```